# Chrome can't open localhost:3000 with Gulp / BrowserSync

Tags: google-chrome, gulp, browser-sync

For some reason, no matter what I try, Google Chrome never seems to be able to display http://localhost:3000 (or any other specified port number for that matter) when starting up a server with BrowserSync through Gulp.

Navigating to the same URI in Firefox, shows that it works and that BrowserSync is *connected*.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        },
        port: 8080
    });
});
```

I'm specifying port `8080` above as an *alternative*, but even using the default `3000` does not work in Chrome. Firefox seems to be able to work with either.

I've been to: chrome://net-internals/#dns and cleared the host cache, restarted, etc. Nothing works.

In Chrome I simply get the message: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Any ideas? Thanks.

PS - Also works in Safari.

Comment: Could it be about Chrome's content security policy?

Comment: @Ursus - Not sure, could you elaborate at all? Thanks.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233218/browser-sync-is-blocked-by-chrome-csp).

Comment: @Ursus It was to do with a default entry in the hosts file on a Mac. Answered below!

Comment: Clearing the host cache solved the issue for me for now. I'll report back if this fix is only temporary, which I suspect it to be.

Comment: As suspected it was only a temporary fix. The accepted answer seems to have fixed it. I was worried about editing that file since it was written inside not to change it. Caution be danged.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how were you running the command to stand up the server?  For me, I had to add 'serve' to the end of my command - 'npm run dev serve' did the trick.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out the issue if this helps anybody.

Accessing the site through the public IP that BrowserSync gives worked, but I still needed `localhost:3000`, so I investigated further into the hosts file on Mac.

By default it seems this line was the one affecting the connection:

```
::1    localhost
```

All you have to do is comment this line out and all should be fine:

```
#::1    localhost
```

Hope this helps someone with a similar issue using Gulp and BrowserSync with Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: @thomas This depends on what OS you're using. Every machine has one. I would suggest Googling 'where is the hosts file on [ Windows | Mac | Linux ]' etc, depending on what's relevant to you. The exact location sometimes differs between OS versions too. On my Mac running Yosemite, it's at: /private/etc/hosts - to get there, use the 'Go to folder...' option in Finder under the 'Go' tab.

Comment: For some reason, this made it work on my system. Hosts file at /etc/hosts

Comment: This should be carved in stone on the BrowserSync home page. Lost an entire day on this. Linux here btw

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem for weeks! I finally figured out the direct combination to resolve this on: 
**Mac Sierra 10.12.6.**

Indeed, the answer above with the most points, is correct. However, i found i had to flush my DNS Cache directly after updating my host file, otherwise i would continue to get the white screen of death - DNS caching was my issue :/

Here are the steps that finally resolved this for me:

**1.**
Disconnect any existing gulp servers (and in my case VPN connections that affiliate with the server you are trying to proxy)

**2.**
In your 'hosts' file:

change

```
::1    localhost
```

to

```
#::1    localhost
```

then save that file

**3.**
Open 'Terminal'

**4.**
Copy / paste this into Terminal, then hit enter
(these commands flush your DNS cache)

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;
```

**5.**
Reconnect to VPN (if any), re-run your gulp browsersync command

**And voila!** 
You should be able to get past the white screen, and the forever spinning browser wheel.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problems before, I tried these combinations, sometimes just changing the paths helps.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync',['nodemon'], function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
       // proxy:"http://localhost:3000"
       //server: "./server/app.js"
       proxy:"localhost:3001"

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been successfully using the following in my app.

From my `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {

  // Browser sync config
  browserSync({
      proxy: 'localhost:3000'
  });

});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No joy for me there. Since it works in Firefox and Safari but not Chrome, I feel there must be something more going on with Chrome itself.

Answer (score 0):

Manually setting the browser property in the init function worked for me.

```
gulp.task('browserSync', () => {
        browserSync.init({
            server: {
                baseDir: task.dir.base,
                middleware: [
                    webpackDevMiddleware(bundler, {
                        publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
                        stats: 'errors-only'
                    })
                  ]
            },
            browser: 'chrome'
        });
    });
```

*I'm running windows 10 x64*

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11, I've edited my hosts file at Windows/System32/drivers/etc, by adding new mapping for 127.0.0.1 to my project external URL and now it works!

```
127.0.0.1   www.myname.test
127.0.0.1   myname.test
```

I'm using tailpress theme builder for wordpress which includes browsersync support :)
Thanks for [michael-giovanni-pumo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695749/michael-giovanni-pumo) for providing me with idea

Answer (score 0):

Soo... I tried every method provided here but nothing worked.
I was just messing with some different ways and finally got it to work

I just set a www in front of the domain like this

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {

    // Browser sync config
    browserSync({
        port:3333,
        proxy: "http://www.name.local",
    });
});
```