# BrowserSync no longer loads localhost:3000 since Anvil/Pow install

Tags: apache, gulp, mamp, browser-sync, pow

I have been using **BrowserSync** and **Gulp** to proxy **MAMP** sites with a simple Gulp task that looks something like this:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        proxy: "site-name.localhost"
    });
});
```

Ever since I installed Anvil for Mac which requires Pow, the http://localhost:3000 url that BrowserSync used to resolve, instead it now hangs and doesn't resolve.

It happens in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. I've tried commenting out this line in my hosts file as suggested in [Chrome can't open localhost:3000 with Gulp / BrowserSync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171725/chrome-cant-open-localhost3000-with-gulp-browsersync)

```
#::1    localhost
```

And I've tried putting all sorts of URLs in the `proxy:` line including localhost:3000 and changing the port number - neither of which get me back to where I was before the Pow install.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone's looking for an answer. uninstalling Pow + Anvil seems to fix it.

```
curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh
```