# BrowserSync Gulp doesn't open in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I try to open my website on localhost using BrowserSync and Gulp in Chrome, but it doesn't work. Default, it open in Firefox and everything works well. But, when I change params in gulpfile.js to open website in Chrome - I have this information:

> [Browsersync] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a
>   headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
>   My config in gulpfile.js:

```
// browser-sync options
// see: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/
var browserSyncOptions = {
    browser: "google chrome",
    proxy: "localhost",
    notify: false
};
```

I tried "chrome", "chrome-browser", nothing happend. What I should to do?
Notice: I have Ubuntu 17.04, Chrome is my default browser.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171725/chrome-cant-open-localhost3000-with-gulp-browsersync?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is with your port, try to change your proxy to below :

```
var browserSyncOptions = {
    browser: "google chrome",
    proxy: "localhost:3001",
    notify: false
};
```

and check your website in chrome with this port :

```
http://localhost:3001
```

Update :

Also try to use the same port in browserSync :

```
browserSync({ 
   proxy: 'localhost:3001' 
});
```

Comment: still this same information in console + website not loaded with 3001 port in url ;(

Comment: @Marek Try to add the same port to browserSync and try again, something like browserSync({
      proxy: 'localhost:3001'
  });

Comment: it doesn't work, not sync..but I if restart Apache, the default config (without browser: "google chrome") works...I don't know where was (is?) problem. Apache is changing port when restarting?

Comment: It can, find httpd.conf file and check for port there, if u use xamp it is usually in apache\conf\httpd.conf folder

Comment: For me,  it only worked with: browser: "google-chrome", on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping Google from browser sync call...
var browserSyncOptions = {
    browser: "google chrome",
    proxy: "localhost:3001",
    notify: false
};

So you just have chrome.
var browserSyncOptions = {
    browser: "chrome",
    proxy: "localhost:3001",
    notify: false
};