# Allow All Content Security Policy?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, xss, content-security-policy

Is it possible to configure the Content-Security-Policy to not block anything at all? I'm running a computer security class, and our web hacking project is running into issues on newer versions of Chrome because without any CSP headers, it's automatically blocking certain XSS attacks.

Answer (score 90):

For people who still want an even more permissive posts, because the other answers were just not permissive enough, and they must work with google chrome for which `*` is just not enough:

```
default-src * data: mediastream: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; 
script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
frame-src * data: blob: ; 
style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
frame-ancestors * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
```

Comment: For a policy that allows inline, but not from any host, the wildcards ( * ) could be changed to "self".

Comment: Chrome now says it doesn't know and will ignore `'unsafe-dynamic'`

Comment: @AnatoliiBivol interesting, I guess you can remove it to avoid warnings, if chrome is the only thing you care about

Comment: I also needed to add frame-ancestors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

Comment: As if a directive is not found a fallback will be applied to the 'default-src' directive, why don't you consider something like that: default-src * data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'

Comment: @AhmedEl-Atab at the time of writing, chrome required defining each entry explicitly.

Comment: New version on 2022: default-src *  data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';  script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';  connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';  img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';  frame-src * data: blob: ;  style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors * data: blob:;

Comment: Is the above a bad policy for a public website?

Comment: @badams depends on your purpose

Comment: @Rainb I would like to check the box for "having a CSP", while neither breaking the website, nor taking a step backwards in security.

Comment: @badams I assume this CSP is for websites that have information that should be accessible by anyone even in other websites, you have to decide for yourself if this suits your purpose.  or maybe you're testing localhost and can't bother with csp at the moment

Answer (score 43):

It's not secure at all, but as staring point the  **real allow all policy** is:

```
default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';
```

See: https://content-security-policy.com/ and [this CSP migration guide](https://blog.codeship.com/how-to-get-started-with-a-content-security-policy/).

Comment: Blob and data missed,  example:  default-src *  data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';

Comment: You missed font-src: * 'unsafe-inline';

Comment: Coooool. save my time

Answer (score 19):

The best way would be not applying any policy.

But to answer your question, an "allow all policy" would probably be:

```
default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;
```

Note: untested

Comment: Unfortunately without any policy in place, Chrome proactively adds some XSS protections of its own, so having nothing is actually worse. But thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Here's the htaccess code to allow everything in CSP

```
Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src *  data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-dynamic'; script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src * data: blob: ; style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';"
```

Answer (score 2):

> DISCLAIMER/WARNING: **Please consider writing a proper CSP**. The following configuration allows any connection and **does not** provide any security benefit. The Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only header helps you to archive the goal of a proper CSP in two steps/non-blocking.

Since the default behavior is for every policy to fall back to default-src (according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src)), the simplest CSP header that allows anything should be this:

```yaml
default-src * data: mediastream: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-eval' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
```

The explanation why `*` does not match "everything" is, that the asterix only allows all host-sources, but e.g. schema-sources, inline or eval are not host-sources. Therefore these types of sources must be explicitly specified.