# Instagram captcha error on new app creation

Tags: instagram-api

When I try to create an instagram client (developer side), I'm always getting the same error:

> Captcha invalid, please try again
>  
>   Submission error: please fill out all required fields.

All fields are correctly set and captcha is good. (I tried many times, but always same error)

Someone have a solution for me?

Answer (score 12):

If you look at the console, we can see there is an error related to "Content Security Policy" which avoid loading google captcha script :

[image: Consent Security Policy]

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356214/disabling-content-security-policy) there is no easy way to disable "Content Security Policy" in Chrome except by using an extension. 
Such an extension is available here : [Disable Content Security Policy [Google Chrome extension]](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden?hl=en)

Once the extension is active, the instagram form loads without errors and should look like this :

[image]

For security reason I highly recommend to uninstall the extension once the app is created.

Comment: Wow I've been at this for more than 2 hours and this answer allowed the captcha to show up, allowing me to complete this form finally.

Answer (score 10):

I am getting the same errors, tried different browsers and even computers, no luck. I think its broken for everyone...

Edit: To clarify this is the form with the broken Captcha https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/register/ and seems to prevent any new clients from being created.

Edit2: Tried the following devices

- Win10 w/ Chrome v61.0.3163.100
- Android 7.12 w/ Chrome v61.0.3163.98

SUCCESS: Worked only on a **MacOS(Sierra 10.12.5) with Safari**. Tried with Chrome v60.x and still did not work on the Mac. Only Safari seems to work.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? i retry today and always same error

Comment: try with chrome on mobile, it works for me, but none wth safari

Comment: I tried now with Safari on my mac and it worked for me.

Comment: For me it worked on Safari on iOS 10.3.2. I entered the CAPTCHA answer in the field and then went back to the redirect URI field and pressed Enter/Go while that field was highlighted. Only place I could get it to work.

Comment: Didn't work for Safari for me on Sierra. Worked with chrome on android.

Comment: Had the same issue today and it worked for me on Safari 11.0 on Sierra 10.12.6. Didn't work with chrome.

Comment: For me, NOTHING WORKS. Tried Windows 10 and Mac OS. Android. Different browsers on each. Incognito mode. Long description. Nothing. I'm amazed Instagram did this so badly. Is there another way? More things to try?

Answer (score 7):

Just go to your Google Chrome in your mobile phone (mine is Android) and it should work.

It worked for me ;)

Comment: thanks ! it works for me, but only with chrome (on iOS in my case)

Comment: I tried it on all my desktop browsers, and the first time I tried it on mobile it worked. Great tip!

Comment: Weird I tried it on my Android 7.12 w/ Chrome v61.0.3163.98 and it did not work. A mac with Safari was the only way I could get it to save.

Answer (score 4):

Well. I found a solution.
I had the same problem. Simply do that from your cellphone and it works.

**Update**: The Android Chrome version that I used is: 61.0

Comment: You tried on your browser's phone ? I try on my iphone with safari and i got the same error from captcha invalid.

Comment: I tried as well on my Andorid/Chrome phone and this did not work. Still the same error as desktop.

Comment: Why down vote, this solution just made my day, Thank you @MohArjmandi!

Comment: I was only able to successfully register via Safari on my iPhone. No desktop browser worked (Chrome, FireFox, Safari). They all gave the same error messages.

Comment: Well I am not sure if the deliberately prevent registration on desktop or not, But weirdly it does not work on desktop browsers @JaredH

Answer (score 3):

https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/register/

This form is broken, throws below error:

> The captcha solution was not correct. Please try again.
>
> Submission error: please fill out all required fields.

Comment: Can confirm, still broken. Tried multiple browsers and also on my phone.

Answer (score 3):

For those who just want the access the api and dont need a client id this is a workarround.
I mangaged to get an access_token through http://instagram.pixelunion.net/

So i can still load images from my profile on my site

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{userid}/media/recent/?access_token={generated_accesscode}
```

Comment: yes it's a great solution, i used it too. But i don't understand why this form is broken and why instagram does nothing.

It works for safari/mac for someone, for chrome for other, and nothing sometimes... incredible :)

Comment: @romaniTO Yeah I tried like all browsers on my mac, used a windows PC, android and iPhone browsers... nothing worked... so I found this solution and it was all I need. No need to have a client id for my purposes

Comment: lmao, how come multi-billion dollars company can't fix form and it's been a year already

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me in a Incognito window in Google Chrome

Comment: Worked for me in Incognito too. Instagram sucks but its how it is.

Comment: Worked for me once in incognito mode in Chrome. Not again. Must have tried 15+ different devices/browser combos, and nothing works now.

Comment: This just worked for me as of 10/18, I tried every other single combination suggested in this thread without success.

Answer (score 2):

The captcha doesn't event show up for me on any browser on OS. Mobile or desktop. In the end I just didn't use a client ID and the user Id and access token seem to be enough for me to access my feed.

https://codeofaninja.com/tools/find-instagram-user-id

http://instagram.pixelunion.net/

Comment: Very nice. This looks much more promising than scraping json from the html source

Answer (score 0):

***You have to press enter after typing your redirect_url.***

Don't just click or tab to the next field.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by inserting a longer value in the description form input and by using the Firefox browser... What a joke !

I don't understand the matter but it's the only way I found.

I hope it will help someone here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Android app, Android Chrome, Android Firefox, and Laptop's Chrome. None of them worked... Finally I tried Laptop's Firefox and it worked like a charm... I happened to get a captcha with 3 words. Actually it was 2 signs but the second one has a road name and a number.

Answer (score 0):

It works on latest version of firefox (v 55.0.3 32-bit) for me on windows 8.1.

Tried on android chrome, but that would not even let me open instagram.

I just finished creating couple of applications.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me using Chrome on macOS High Sierra.  Chrome version is 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Exact same operating system and browser version but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I got the form to successfully submit the first time round using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 in Firefox 54.0.1.

No version of Safari or Chrome would work for me.

Had the very same error:

> The captcha solution was not correct. Please try again.
>
> Submission error: please fill out all required fields.

Hope Firefox solves the issue for all.

Answer (score 0):

Worked immediately on Firefox without a hiccup.

```
Firefox:55.0.3 (64-bit)

OSX Sierra: 10.12.6 (16G29)
```

Didn't work on Safari or Chrome.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different OS (Windows/Linux/Mac OS/iOS/Android) and browser (Chrome/Safari/Firefox/IE) combinations with absolutely no luck. I contacted instagram and reported this issue and I recommend you do the same.

In the meantime, I found this temporary workaround. I went ahead a generated an access token using this link: [Instagram Pixel Union](http://instagram.pixelunion.net)

Now I can continue doing the development work while waiting for the response from instagram. I also sent the request to them for information