# Call to eval() blocked by CSP with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, eval, selenium-ide, content-security-policy

I have a selenium test developed in `Selenium IDE`. I have a step in this suite that should type a value in a text field. It fails at that step giving the following error:

```
18. click on id=firstName Failed:11:12:59
call to eval() blocked by CSP
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### CSP

Content Security Policy [(CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSP) acts as a added layer of security that helps to detect and mitigate attacks including Cross Site Scripting [(XSS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross-site_scripting) and data injection attacks. These attacks are primarily used for data theft and distribution of malware.

---

This error message...

```
call to eval() blocked by CSP
```

...implies that the **add-on** which is being used by the *Selenium IDE* doesn't include `'unsafe-eval'` in CSP header.

As per the discussion [Firefox add-on needs 'unsafe-eval' in CSP header](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/issues/471) the earlier version of Firefox were not able to detect [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) based application if the server sends the *Content Security Policy* header without `'unsafe-eval'` in the `script-src` directive.

This issue was discussed at length within the discussion [Convert Firefox add-on to use the Chrome WebExtension](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/issues/666) and was addressed through a installable *WebExtension* which can be found [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ember-inspector/).

---

### Update

As per OP's comment an easier approach would be to tweak the following *Key-Value* within `about:config` which solves the issue:

```
security.csp.enable    off
```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in [Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: script-src error with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207838/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po/59213413#59213413)

Comment: Just turning `security.csp.enable` off  in firefox `about:config` worked well for me

Comment: Are you just using the Selenium tests on a Dev server?  If so I would leave CSP turned on for the Production server

Comment: Disabling `security.csp.enable` is no more available since Firefox 99 (see [Consider removing security.csp.enable pref](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1754301)). Thus the updated solution doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling CSP in `about:config` is [no longer possible since Firefox 99](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1754301).

Another solution consists in using a web extension, where you can be more selective on what you enable/disable.

Let say we want to authorize execution of JS (`script-src: 'unsafe-eval'`) on `https://www.example.org/`:

First install the
[Firefox extension ModHeader](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/modheader-firefox/) (it is also available on other browsers). Once installed,
open the panel:

[image]

Click on the `+` icon and add a `Response header`: as name type `Content-Security-Policy` and as value type `script-src: 'unsafe-eval'`.

Click on more time on the `+` icon and add a `Filter`. For the `URL pattern` type `https:\/\/www.example.org/`.

[image]

You may choose precisely what to enable/disable on [CSP website](https://content-security-policy.com/).

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, the [`security.csp.enable` option has been removed as of Firefox 99](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1754301). While there are third party extensions to allow manipulating the CSP header ([as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426099/call-to-eval-blocked-by-csp-with-selenium-ide#answer-72059194)), be sure that the author is trustworthy.

There is also an official Mozilla extension that can be used too: [Laboratory](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/laboratory-by-mozilla/), with an associated [Laboratory video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oan4J9kfy44).

Once installed, the basic steps:

1. Open the site you'd like to test with Selenium IDE
2. Click on the Laboratory extension
3. Choose "Custom CSP policy"
4. Add a permissive CSP as required e.g. [allow everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978863/allow-all-content-security-policy#answer-51067035)
5. Save the policy then run Selenium IDE as normal

Comment: Apparently [Laboratory](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/laboratory-by-mozilla/) is no longer an official add-on.