# Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: script-src error with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver, content-security-policy

I am trying to scrape Phone Number from these links "https://www.practo.com/delhi/doctor/dr-meeka-gulati-dentist-3?specialization=Dentist&practice_id=722421" and "https://www.practo.com/delhi/doctor/dr-rajeev-puri-ear-nose-throat-ent-specialist?specialization=Ear-Nose-Throat%20(ENT)%20Specialist&practice_id=912154"

if element present it scrapes the phone number otherwise phone number is None

**Spider Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.practo.com/delhi/doctor/dr-meeka-gulati-dentist-3?specialization=Dentist&practice_id=722421')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@data-a-target='carousel-broadcaster-displayname']"))
                            )
try:
    next1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="c-btn--light c-btn--center"]')
    next1.click()

    next2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="u-title-font icon-ic_call_filled u-valign--middle"]')
    next2.click()
    phone_number = driver.find_element_by_class_name('c-vn__number').get_attribute('innerHTML')
except NoSuchElementException:
    phone_number = None

print(phone_number)
```

**Output**

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60482/devtools/browser/9f226a40-2d1a-4108-9fde-f005b49e60b3
[1206/102937.475:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[Report Only] Refused to load the script 
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-942004674' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-3RJz12sDPuoV27qS7dcBXLRZawmPobLo' *.practo.com *.practostatic.com *.onesignal.com *.mxpnl.com *.mixpanel.com *.facebook.com *.facebook.net *.twitter.com *.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com *.google.com *.googlesyndication.com *.newrelic.com *.google-analytics.com *.googletagmanager.com *.googleadservices.com *.googlesyndication.com *.doubleclick.net *.survicate.com in.wzrkt.com *.nr-data.net *.newrelic.com *.speedcurve.com *.ampproject.org *.netcore.co.in *.netcoresmartech.com *.criteo.net *.criteo.com https://secure.livechatinc.com". 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based whitelisting is disabled. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

", source: https://www.practo.com/delhi/doctor/dr-rajeev-puri-ear-nose-throat-ent-specialist?specialization=Ear-Nose-Throat%20(ENT)%20Specialist&practice_id=912154 (0)
[1206/125829.645:INFO:CONSOLE(33)] "[Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-eNRfqc27QHPklLLhavu92zuUGDeEoSZL' *.practo.com *.practostatic.com *.onesignal.com *.mxpnl.com *.mixpanel.com *.facebook.com *.facebook.net *.twitter.com *.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com *.google.com *.googlesyndication.com *.newrelic.com *.google-analytics.com *.googletagmanager.com *.googleadservices.com *.googlesyndication.com *.doubleclick.net *.survicate.com in.wzrkt.com *.nr-data.net *.newrelic.com *.speedcurve.com *.ampproject.org *.netcore.co.in *.netcoresmartech.com *.criteo.net *.criteo.com https://secure.livechatinc.com". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.
    ", source: https://www.practo.com/delhi/doctor/dr-rajeev-puri-ear-nose-throat-ent-specialist?specialization=Ear-Nose-Throat%20(ENT)%20Specialist&practice_id=912154 (33)
[1206/125829.829:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://9535906.fls.doubleclick.net/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' https://survicate.com *.practo.com *.criteo.net *.criteo.com https://www.facebook.com https://bid.g.doubleclick.net https://secure.livechatinc.com".
", source: https://www.googletagmanager.com/ (0)
[1206/125830.508:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://9535906.fls.doubleclick.net/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' https://survicate.com *.practo.com *.criteo.net *.criteo.com https://www.facebook.com https://bid.g.doubleclick.net https://secure.livechatinc.com".
", source: https://www.googletagmanager.com/ (0)
```

Comment: That's normal behavior, csp is keeping you safe from potential xss attacks.

Comment: @RaoTauqeerSajid What are you trying to scrape exactly? With which elements are you trying to interact?

Comment: i have 1000 links of that website i want to get phone number if there available by clicking the button call button

Comment: I edited my question as what I want to do

Comment: @RaoTauqeerSajid I don't see the _phone number_ even.

Comment: Right, I don't think that disabling CSP even solves your issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
[1206/102937.475:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[Report Only] Refused to load the script 
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-942004674' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-3RJz12sDPuoV27qS7dcBXLRZawmPobLo' *.practo.com *.practostatic.com *.onesignal.com *.mxpnl.com *.mixpanel.com *.facebook.com *.facebook.net *.twitter.com *.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com *.google.com *.googlesyndication.com *.newrelic.com *.google-analytics.com *.googletagmanager.com *.googleadservices.com *.googlesyndication.com *.doubleclick.net *.survicate.com in.wzrkt.com *.nr-data.net *.newrelic.com *.speedcurve.com *.ampproject.org *.netcore.co.in *.netcoresmartech.com *.criteo.net *.criteo.com https://secure.livechatinc.com". 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based whitelisting is disabled. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
.
[1206/125830.508:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://9535906.fls.doubleclick.net/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' https://survicate.com *.practo.com *.criteo.net *.criteo.com https://www.facebook.com https://bid.g.doubleclick.net https://secure.livechatinc.com".
", source: https://www.googletagmanager.com/ (0)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

### Content Security Policy (CSP)

To mitigate the cross-site scripting issues Chrome's extension system has implemented the concept of [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/) which introduces some strict policies that will make extensions more secure by default and provides us the ability to create and enforce rules governing the types of content that can be loaded and executed by your extensions and applications. CSP works as a block/allowlisting mechanism for resources loaded or executed by your extensions. Defining a reasonable policy for your extension enables you to consider the resources that your extension requires and to negotiate with the browser to ensure that those are the only resources your extension has access to. These policies provide security even above the [host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) your extension requests acting as an additional layer of protection. Such policies are defined via an HTTP header or meta element. Within Chrome's extension system the extension's policy is defined via the extension's [manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) file as follows:

```
{
  "content_security_policy": "[POLICY STRING GOES HERE]"
}
```

---

### Relaxing the Content Security Policy

Till Chrome 45, there was no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, setting a script policy that includes 'unsafe-inline' will have no effect. However, from Chrome 46 onwards, inline scripts can be allowed by specifying the base64-encoded hash of the source code in the policy. This hash must be prefixed by the used hash algorithm (sha256, sha384 or sha512). This can be achived by setting adding **`http://*`** to both `style-src` and/or `script-src` as follows:

```
script-src 'self' http://xxxx 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
```

and/or

```
style-src 'self' http://xxxx 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
```

---

### This usecase

However I was able to access the webpage https://www.practo.com/delhi/doctor/dr-rajeev-puri-ear-nose-throat-ent-specialist?specialization=Ear-Nose-Throat%20(ENT)%20Specialist&practice_id=912154 easily as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.practo.com/delhi/doctor/dr-rajeev-puri-ear-nose-throat-ent-specialist?specialization=Ear-Nose-Throat%20(ENT)%20Specialist&practice_id=912154")
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html><head><title>Dr. Rajeev Puri - ENT/ Otorhinolaryngologist - Book Appointment Online, View Fees, Feedbacks | Practo</title><meta name="description" content="Dr. Rajeev Puri is an ENT/ Otorhinolaryngologist in DLF Phase IV. Book appointments Online, View Fees, User Feedbacks for Dr. Rajeev Puri | Practo"><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"><script src="https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-spa-1026.min.js"></script><script src="//survey.survicate.com/workspaces/wfhrNWYKtlLEWMqcaXcweuzHeMRiSljw/web_surveys.js" async=""></script><script src="//api.survicate.com/assets/survicate.js" async=""></script><script src="//survey.survicate.com/workspaces/wfhrNWYKtlLEWMqcaXcweuzHeMRiSljw/web_surveys.js" async=""></script><script src="//api.survicate.com/assets/survicate.js" async=""></script><script src="https://surveys-static.survicate.com/widget_core-3.0.4.js" async=""></script><script src="//survey.survicate.com/workspaces/wfhrNWYKtlLEWMqcaXcweuzHeMRiSljw/web_surveys.js" async=""></script><script src="//survey.survicate.com/workspaces/wfhrNWYKtlLEWMqcaXcweuzHeMRiSljw/web_surveys.js" async=""></script><script src="//survey.survicate.com/workspaces/wfhrNWYKtlLEWMqcaXcweuzHeMRiSljw/web_surveys.js" async=""></script><script src="//api.survicate.com/assets/survicate.js" async=""></script><script src="//api.survicate.com/assets/survicate.js" async=""></script><script src="//api.survicate.com/assets/survicate.js" async=""></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" nonce=""></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ec.js" nonce=""></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.practostatic.com/pel/clevertap/a.js"></script><script async="" src="//sweep.practo.com/sp.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.practostatic.com/pel/pel-1.6.1.js"></script><script async="" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js"></script><script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-PSMVGL5"></script><script nonce="" type="text/javascript">(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                })(window,document,'script','dataLayer',"GTM-PSMVGL5");</script>
  ```

---

### Additional Considerations

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in [Call to eval() blocked by CSP with Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426099/call-to-eval-blocked-by-csp-with-selenium-ide/57427401#57427401)

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a chrome devtools protocal command for this but it's marked experimental:

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setBypassCSP", {"enabled": True})
```