# Cannot execute script selenium because of: “The devicemotion events are blocked by feature policy.”

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I don't know why but i encounter this issue in only payment part. I execute script with other pages but i didn't get this warning.

```
def payments(self, cvc):
    print("Paying for the shoe.")
    self.chrome.execute_script("scroll(0, 300)") # for seeing buttons
    # Need class and name at the same time because it is inside in iframe
    self.wait_until_visible(xpath="//input[@class='pre-search-input headline-5' and @name='cardCvc']")
    cvc_input = self.chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='pre-search-input headline-5' and @name='cardCvc']")
    cvc_input.clear()
    cvc_input.send_keys(cvc)
    self.wait_until_clickable(xpath="//button[@class='button button-continue']")
    self.chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='button button-continue']").click()
    self.wait_until_clickable(xpath="//button[@class='button button-submit']")
    self.chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='button button-submit']").click()
    print("Payment taken.")
```

This is my code that does not running. Before that error I encountered with another error like this: `Refused to load the script 'http because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive with ChromeDriver Chrome headless Selenium.`

[I solved this error with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207838/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po): `self.chrome.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setBypassCSP", {"enabled": True}) #  to disable Contect Security Policy`

Now i stuck at this error: `The devicemotion events are blocked by feature policy. See https://github.com/WICG/feature-policy/blob/master/features.md#sensor-features polyfills.14f35e1be48465411559.js:1`

I create my driver like this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/caner/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome")
self.chrome = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
self.chrome.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setBypassCSP", {"enabled": True})
```

Do you think i handle Content Security Policy in a right way. The difference between others pages and payment page is iframe. If you have any idea about this please let me know.

My Error is `The devicemotion events are blocked by feature policy.` at some specific page(payment page). I just told there might be possibility. However it might not be related to iframe, or such thing Content Security Policy. I was just guessing. Is there any one have idea about this error?

I didnt see the same issue those links.
[Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe) (2 answers)
[How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium) (2 answers)
[Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: script-src error with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207838/refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security-po)
Also the last link i applied their solution it seems that it solves the CSP problem. But i have new problem (The devicemotion events are blocked by feature policy.). Thats why it should not be duplicated question.

Comment: devicemotion events are for phones... anything that detects acceleration.  Shouldn't affect you at all.  I'm guessing these errors are generated by the page you are visiting which is running cross-domain scripts.  In an iframe?  Bypassing the content security policy is not a great idea... especially if you exposing any login info.  There's a reason for restricting cross-origin scripts.

Comment: I agree,this seems like it's a browser console error, is that true?

Comment: If i want to run script in payment page, how can i able to do that without bypassing content security policy. @pcalkins
Additional info: "Payments page fill my credit card and my billing address automatically, probably take this data with relation from my account.".

Comment: Yes, it is console error. @DMart

Comment: Yes i can see that clearly now. These console errors are happen when i normally enter the website as well. I thought that those errors occurs when i try to execute_script. As you said i dont bypass content security policy now. Also i can execute my down scroll script. Thanks a lot for your help @pcalkins

Comment: What was the solution here?