# Issue playing a video on Jenkins HTML Publisher

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ui-automation, testcafe

I am using Testcafe for my project tests and I am generating a HTML report with screenshot and video in my project.

When I am trying to publish the report using HTML publisher, the video is not playing.
When I open the generated HTML file in the Jenkins agent via browser, the video is playing fine. not sure, why it is not playing on the Jenkins HTML publisher plugin.

MY HTML video code looks like below

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
      <img id="myImg" class="errImage" src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABAAAA" style="width:100%;">  
   </div>
   <div class="column">
      <video autoplay muted loop controls id="errorVideo" style="width:99%">
         <source src="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Free style node test\e2e\artifacts\videos\Getting Started\My First Test\1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried configuring following **content security policy**

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox; default-src '';")
```

not sure what policy is blocking the video from playing on the Jenkins publisher.

Can someone help to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to use url path related to jenkins fqdn + build artifact ? example: http://localhost/Free%20style%20node%20test/e2e/artifacts/videos/Getting%20Started/My%20First%20Test/1.mp4

Comment: yes, I tried that one as well still no use :(

Comment: Try setting CSP as illustrated in this thread: [Allow All Content Security Policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978863/allow-all-content-security-policy).

Answer (score 3):

The policy which blocking your video from playing is media-src == "none", derived from default-src == 'none' (see https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy)

Take a look at the solution in https://github.com/jenkinsci/screenrecorder-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/screenrecorder/ScreenRecorderBuildWrapper.java, it could work for you:

```
String curCsp = System.getProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP","");
if (!curCsp.contains("media-src"))
{
       System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", curCsp + ";media-src 'self';");
}
```

Comment: I executed your script through script console, still, the video is not getting displayed through HTML Publisher plugin.

Comment: What is the return value of System.getProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP","") after your script execution?

Comment: I ran this `String curCsp = System.getProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP","");
println(curCsp)`

I got result as 
`;media-src 'self';`

Comment: Maybe the execution in the script console doesn't have any impact on global properties? Tyr to this parameter to empty string in your jenkins start script,
example:  -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= -DJENKINS_HOME=...