# How to get past CSP (Content Security Policy) by allowing everything?

Tags: html, deployment, content-security-policy, netlify

The website works perfectly on local machine, but when I upload it to netlify it drops near [20 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09c8H.png).

I just want to share one of my first projects with friends and not be bothered with security right now.

Tried implementing all the answers from this [Allow All Content Security Policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978863/allow-all-content-security-policy) post, but still nothing.

This is my header that's getting the previously mentioned 20 errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
      default-src *  data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-dynamic'; 
      script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
      connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
      img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
      frame-src * data: blob: ; 
      style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
      font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

But trying all the other answers also resulted in something similar.

Comment: The way is, don't add any `meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` element to the document at all, and don't send any Content-Security-Policy at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same happened to me recently, you likely have a browser extension running that blocks scripts.

That's why you probably cannot even see these headers in google dev tools.

Disable it for that site and voila ;)

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have a CSP published via HTTP header, this CSP has a characteristic `script-src-elem 'none'` rule (underlined in BLUE in the print screen).
You added CSP via the meta tag, this CSP has a characteristic `'unsafe-dynamic'` token (underlined in GREEN in the print screen).
[image]

You can't relax first Content Security Policy by adding a second one.

Like as comment by sideshowbarker, just remove CSP in HTTP header. Check if you have *netlify-plugin-csp-generator* or *netlify-plugin-csp-headers* [Netlify packages](https://csplite.com/csp249/#CSP_Netlify) installed. Those can publish default CSP via HTTP header.

Comment: Ok, so I removed the <meta> tag, installed the -csp-generator with npm and created a [netlify.toml file](https://i.imgur.com/9ejmPD7.png) where I tried multiple variations. Still getting the same errors where it doesn't like the [gsap CDN](https://i.imgur.com/hAKDBb8.png) and same [CSP issues](https://i.imgur.com/iTFj78j.png). Do I have to change all the * to 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' and so on? Am I even on the right path? Why do no netlify tutorials mention anything about this / so few posts about it, why am I running into these issues with my basic single-page web app?

Comment: On the contrary, I suggested removing all packages that can publish CSP  On local machine you do not have any troubles, only with Netlify because some packages publish default CSP. Remove meta and csp-packages installed. Then check do you still have a CSP header, tutorial is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060894/trouble-with-content-security-policy/64068629#64068629). And check that no `<meta CSP>` presents in the HTML code..

Comment: omg, I'm such a dunce... I for some reason didn't realise that it could be my noScript extension that's blocking the .js files. So yeah, doesn't look like I even needed all the CSP stuff, but thank you for bothering to try and help! -_-'

Comment: An interesting twist. Could you confirm that noScript extension block the .js files and it's observed as Content Security Policy blocking in the console?

Comment: Not sure what confirmation you need, but I was wondering why so many errors referenced the ...netlify.app/, as it's something that I have no control over. And when I finally checked the devtool network tab, noticed that both mine and gsap scripts are in red and then it clicked. As soon as I set the app to trusted in noScript, everything worked. And the script-blocked console screenshots can be seen above